# Calling a Component from Ajax in CakePHP

Tags: ajax, cakephp, components

I've been developing a web application in CakePHP 2.x that uses an [Image cropping tool](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) to manipulate an image. Currently it passes Ajax calls to handle the manipulation onto a function within the current Controller which then calls a Component which contains the main processing and functionality.

I'm currently going through and refactoring this section of the code and I was wondering if it's possible to directly call the Component from Ajax and whether or not it is a good idea or not as it would simplify a chunk of the code if possible.

Thoughts, opinions and tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: No, usually you should have a controller action then invoking the component call explicitly.

Comment: Simply.. You can't do it. And that's not how you do things.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm currently going through and refactoring this section of the code and I was wondering if it's possible to directly call the Component from Ajax and whether or not it is a good idea or not as it would simplify a chunk of the code if possible.

It's not a good idea because this is how components are thought to be used. A component is not thought to receive a request directly but to provide additional - reuseable functionality - to the controlller level in the MVC pattern.

[Taken from the documentation:](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#components)

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers. CakePHP comes with a fantastic set of core components you can use to aid in various common tasks. You can also create your own components. If you find yourself wanting to copy and paste things between controllers, you should consider creating your own component to contain the functionality. Creating components keeps controller code clean and allows you to reuse code between projects.